# Disjunction in the body of a rule in clingo

Tags: clingo

I think this is basic, but how do you do disjunction with literals to the body of a rule in clingo?   I tried

`p3 :- p1 ; p2.` But it does not work and it assumes the answers of

`p3 :- p1 , p2.`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disjunctions in bodies are only "implicit".
This means you can achive this by using two rules:

```
p3 :- p1.
p3 :- p2.
```

Or using first order variables

```
p(3) :- p(1..2).
```

or

```
dom(1..2).
p(3) :- p(X), dom(X).
```

All three versions are grounded into the same set of rules

```
p(3):-p(2).
p(3):-p(1).
```

(If `p(1)` and `p(2)` are actually deriveable)
You can check this by adding the line

```
{p(X) : dom(X)}.
```

and using `clingo --text`.